# Как создать список Node и передать его в другой класс? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, коллекции

Задача такова: нужно нарисовать 2 линии на `Pane`:
Есть класс **Locomotive** в котором рисуются линии:

```
@Override
public void drawLocomotive() {
     drawBaseLocomotive();
}

protected Node drawBaseLocomotive() {
     Line line = new Line(30,40,50,60);
     Line line2 = new Line(50,60,70,80);
     return line;
}
```

И класс **Controller**(контроллер XML) в котором есть полотно `drawPanel`:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    Pane drawPanel;

    public void btnSetBaseLocomotive_Click(ActionEvent actionEvent) {   
        Locomotive locomotive = new Locomotive();
        inter = new Locomotive(maxSpeed, maxCountPass, weight, color);
        drawPanel.getChildren().addAll(locomotive.drawBaseLocomotive());
    }
}
```

Как реализовать список,который будет содержать две линии,и затем передать его в

```
drawPanel.getChildren().addAll(locomotive.drawBaseLocomotive());
```

Сейчас он рисует одну линию вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов несколько:

1) Заврапить в другой `Node`

```
protected Node drawBaseLocomotive() {
     Line line = new Line(30,40,50,60);
     Line line2 = new Line(50,60,70,80);
     /* нужно проверять, могут быть смещения*/
     return new Group( line, line2 );
//   return new AnchorPane( line, line2 );
//   return new Pane( line, line2 );
}
```

2) Передать массив или список

```
protected Node[] drawBaseLocomotive() {
     Line line = new Line(30,40,50,60);
     Line line2 = new Line(50,60,70,80);
     return new Node[]{ line, line2 };
}

drawPanel.getChildren().addAll(Arrays.asList(locomotive.drawBaseLocomotive()));
```

```
protected List<Nide> drawBaseLocomotive() {
     Line line = new Line(30,40,50,60);
     Line line2 = new Line(50,60,70,80);
     List<Node> list = new ArrayList<>(2);
     list.addAll( line, line2 );
     return list;
}

drawPanel.getChildren().addAll(locomotive.drawBaseLocomotive());
```

3) Создать класс-кортеж

```
private class Tuple {
    public final Line line, line2;
    public Tuple( Line line, Line line2 ) {
        this.line = line;
        this.line2 = line2;
    }
}

protected Tuple drawBaseLocomotive() {
     Line line = new Line(30,40,50,60);
     Line line2 = new Line(50,60,70,80);
     return new Tuple( line, line2 );
}

Tuple tuple = locomotive.drawBaseLocomotive();
drawPanel.getChildren().addAll(tuple.line,tuple.line2);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, выручили!